# IOS: Memory Issue on living objects and

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiscrollview

I have an image gallery which is developed using `UICollectionView`. After I select multiple images from the gallery and press 'Done'. Selected images will display in a `UIScrollView` (paging on) and those are full screen images that can be scrolled up/down to see other images.

1) Is it ok to have this amount of living objects and heap allocation, when starting the app.'

[image]

2) When I select and scroll through the images of `UIScrollView` allocated memory for images will added to the memory and not release. It will crash the app.

Here are the screens when I start scrolling up/down through the images. It will Increasing the memory consumption also other processes.

[image]

[image]

This is testing on iPhone5, using Activity monitor VM and Real memory going up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to load the images 3 at a time, and not the whole set of images at once.

I mean you can set your Scroll Views array and add as many `[NSNull null]` objects to it as the number of images to be shown. Then, at a particular instance, have only 3 images in that array and after scrolling remove the unnecessary ones or replace it with `[NSNull null]` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling memory is tricky. The best instrument to actually use is the Activity Monitor, which will tell you how much live memory is really being used, unlike Allocations which will tell you more than you need to know.

Also, the maximum amount of memory is dependent on each device. If you really want to know if you're using a lot of memory, just test it on a device. You generally have a lot of flexibility, and the internal UIImage class does a lot of fancy caching and clearing of said caching for you.

Comment: See my edits, I used the activity monitor, It also shows memory increasing.